# Why android:background="@null" causing the issue while apply pro-guard rules?

Tags: android, android-layout

So this happens with me that when I was apply pro-guard rules for my app. I was stuck with the error.

The Error

```
Expecting class member name before '@' in line aapt_rules.txt
```

So I was searching for this on the Internet and somewhere found that Remove @null from .xml file and it should work. And it's worked. So my question is why @null is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

proguard tried to use "null" as a name for a **class member** when it meets `@null`, this is a [known issue](https://android.okhelp.cz/proguard-parseexception-expecting-class-member-name-before/). you could delete

```
android:background="@null"
```

and replace with java code:

```
xxx.setBackground(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

a class member's name cannot be `NULL`, because that is a reserved keyword in Java.